# Trying to create, and populate two views dynamically inside a for loop in iOS

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiview

I am trying to iterate through a for loop, and in the process, dynamically build two views, and populate each view with identical UI Elements.  Unfortunately, I'm a little confused because I am not sure how to indicate that the second view is what needs to be populated, and to ignore the first.  Here is the code I am working with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray; i++) {

       UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, COMPONENT_HEIGHT * i, COMPONENT_WIDTH, COMPONENT_HEIGHT)];

       UIImageView *imgView1a = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
       UIImageView *imgView1b = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, 50, 50)];

       UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 150, 55, 55);
       [view addSubview:imgView1a];
       [view addSubview:imgView1b];
       [view addSubview:myButton];

}
```

My problem here is that I am unable to figure out how to create the first view, populate it, and then leave the first view, create the second view, and populate just the second view so that I create and populate two identical views, one below the other, instead of creating one view that gets populated twice.

Comment: Assuming this is going on inside a UIViewController, are you adding 'view' to self.view with [self.view addSubview:view]; at any point?  Seems to me like once you have created the view in your loop, that you need to actually do something with it or it will be overwritten upon the next iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part missing seems to be that you are not adding `view` as a subview of anything, so you'll never see it on the screen. The loop looks OK.